# Line breakage when using write function to write to a file python

Tags: python, file-io

I used write function and sys.stdout to print to file in python script. The problem is line has lots of characters and it splits up into 2 line when printed to a file. I want it printed in a single line.

Ex text- 
" This is the text I want to print in the file, but it ends up writing in two lines because of length" 
The above text is uotput I need, below is the output I'm getting

write(text) or using sys.stdout results in below text - 
output line 1. "This is the text I want to print in the file, but it ends up writing "
output line 2. "in two lines because of length"
The code I'm using is below,

```py
out = subprocess.Popen(
    ['ls',path],
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
)
for i in out.stdout:
    if(re.search(r'(.*?)\.(out)',i)):
        s = p+path+i+q+i
        wp.write(s)
```

where `p`, `path`, `i`, `q` are different strings that are concatenated and written to the file. Sorry for the wrong indentation shown here!

Comment: Please add the code you're running to generate this file. Are you sure it isn't that you have wordwrap on in the file browser?

Comment: Please post the actual code that you are executing. To be sure that it is two lines, check the file in an editor if it has a newline character at the end of the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`write()` does not add new line characters based on character length when writing to a file.

From what you've shown, and after our discussion in the comments, I can say with confidence that either `p`, `path`, `i`, or `q` contains a new line (`"\n"`) character. (and given that `path` is used with `ls`, I highly doubt it's in `path`!)

Add another line of code after you create `s`, like this:

```py
if "\n" in s:
    print("Eureka! A new line exists!")
```

Comment: I'm using Vim editor for viewing the out file, and I even tried printing the output, its printing in 2 lines

Comment: Can you update your question to show the code you're using to generate this line? Also, is your instance of Vim running in a terminal? or a resize-able window? When I run Vim from windows subsystem for linux, I can resize the window, and see that this causes long lines of text to be wrapped, appearing on new lines in the window.

Comment: I running Vim in a linux terminal and I see single line (with one line number) extending to multiple lines because of many characters. The code I'm using is like, I'm joining multiple strings with '+' to form a required string( which has many characters)

Comment: wait - so there is a single line number for this? if there is a single line number, then that's your answer. It is all on a single "line," but your editor / monitor resolution doesn't have the horizontal width to display all your text on a single line. It is all still on the same line.

Comment: no not for the line that is printed by write(), but other text files with lines extending over multiple lines has single line number

Comment: Please share with me how you're creating the string that you're passing to `write()` I think you posted it, then deleted it a moment ago.

Comment: Hey, @Joshua Schlichting ur suggestion was write, it worked